# Default access modifiers not shown in UML Designer 7

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-neon, uml-designer

Why isn't a new **Typed Property** or **Operation** - which has `Public` as default access modifier - marked as public with the green **+** ?

Example:
[image]

The **+** isn't displayed until you switch the **Visibility** from `public` (default) to `private` and then back to `public` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. I add a new issue in the bug tracker : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/909

The issue will be fixed for the next version 7.2 of UML Designer.

An equivalent bug was already fixed for the property creation tool but the bug still exists for the typed property creation tool.

Thanks for your feedback!